# Stuck with for loop (java) for arrays. [i], [i+1],[i+2]

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

So i was on coding bat.com doing a example to practice for my midterm and looking at one of the problems, I got stuck. Why do they do length-2 here in the for loop condition statement.. I don't get why we have to subtract 2, perhaps someone here can quickly explain it. I know its a very simple thing I'm not getting. Thanks!

Question: `

```
Given an array of ints, return true if .. 1, 2, 3, .. appears in the array somewhere. 

array123({1, 1, 2, 3, 1}) → true
array123({1, 1, 2, 4, 1}) → false
array123({1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3}) → true`
```

Solution:

```
public boolean array123(int[] nums) {
  // Note: iterate < length-2, so can use i+1 and i+2 in the loop
  for (int i=0; i < (nums.length-2); i++) {
    if (nums[i]==1 && nums[i+1]==2 && nums[i+2]==3) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Your question is already answered in the comments included in the solution. If you use nums.length, you'll end up with an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: It says so you can use i+1 and i+2 but that doesn't make it clear to me. Sorry I'm a beginner. I want to know why I end up with ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: If you only have three numbers in the array then nums.length will be 3. In the second iteration of the loop where i is 1, if you try to access nums[i+2], you are trying to access num[3], a position that does not exists in your array. In a three length array you only have positions 0, 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to not throw IndexOutOfBound exception. Imagine if you don't have the `-2` and you reach the last element and in the code you are trying to access the element at index (last one + 2), it will throw exception because you want to reach an index which is not available.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for the explanation, i get it now.